# Is it said what kind of tree it is?

Tags: norse, yggdrasil

Is it ever said what kind of tree the world tree was? By kind, I mean type. Is it: oak, laurel, plane, sequaia...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's an ash tree**

In e.g. *Völuspá*, stanza 19, this is explicitly stated:

> An ash I know, 
>  Yggdrasil its name ...

Translation: [Henry Adams Bellow](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/poe/poe03.htm)